# Load pipe delimited file in Weka

Tags: weka

Hi I'm trying to load pipe delimited file in weka using java CSVLoader. Looks like CSVLoader only loads comma and tab. Is there a way i can change the delimiter on these loaders ?

Has anyone loaded a pipe separated file in Weka ?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

The new version does allow you to enter a delimiter or separator using option `-F` option. See: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/CSVLoader.html

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there are any options to give different delimiters. Just read the file first and replace pipes with commas?

Comment: Thanks folks....i did think about replacing pipes to comma, but data is complex... i have |A,B,C| D|E,F| random basis. On top of that my files are huge so another step of converting everything into comma might not be optimal for me. Thanks anyways....i'll shre the utility if i'm able to extend loader and create one.